# Detect fullscreen in pygtk

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I want to be able to detect if my app has been set to fullscreen by the user. I know I can use the `gtk.window.fullscreen()` method to make the window go fullscreen from the code, and the the action also emits a window-state-event signal, but when I wrote the callback I had no way of distinguishing between when the event was activated by a fullscreen request or by a different event like for example minimizing the window to the start bar. How can I detect whether the window has been changed to full screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to check the [event details](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gdk3/unstable/gdk3-Event-Structures.html#GdkEventWindowState).

- To see what user action triggers the event, check `changed_mask`.
- To see the new state (regardless of what causes the event), check `new_window_state`.

Usually this translates into the following code:

```
# Did the user actually toggle fullscreen, or was it
# a different window-state event (e.g. maximize)?
if event.changed_mask & gtk.gdk.WINDOW_STATE_FULLSCREEN:
    # What's the new state?
    print bool(event.new_window_state & gtk.gdk.WINDOW_STATE_FULLSCREEN)
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, so I messed with it a bit and found out that I need to use WINDOW_STATE_MAXIMIZE instead of fullscreen to make it work.